# From multiple JSON data to one table

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have below data in csv file:

```
helpful_reply,reply_by,thread_id
"[{""helpful_reply"":""1 person found this helpful""},{""helpful_reply"":""""},{""helpful_reply"":""1 person found this helpful""}]","[{""reply_by"":""Adam""},{""reply_by"":""John""},{""reply_by"":""Smith""}]","149617"
"[{""helpful_reply"":""1 person found this helpful""},{""helpful_reply"":""""},{""helpful_reply"":""1 person found this helpful""}]","[{""reply_by"":""John""},{""reply_by"":""Mary""},{""reply_by"":""Smith""}]","147223"
```

It contain 3 columns: helpful_reply, reply_by, thread_id

Columns `"helpful_reply"` and `"reply_by"` contain a JSON array.

I want to convert this file to another csv file with a table like below:

```
| helpful_reply               | reply_by   | thread_id |
|-----------------------------|------------|-----------|
| 1 person found this helpful | Adam       | 149617    |
| NULL                        | John       | 149617    |
| 1 person found this helpful | Smith      | 149617    |
| 1 person found this helpful | John       | 147223    |
| NULL                        | Mary       | 147223    |
| 1 person found this helpful | Smith      | 147223    |
```

I've written this code so far and not sure I'm into good approach:

```
import csv
import json
with open('helpful.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    csvreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    ofile=open('output.csv', 'w')
    rownum=0
    for row in csvreader:
        if rownum==0:
            header=row
        else:
            column=0
            for col in row:
                x=col
                x=json.loads(col)
                if isinstance(x,int):
                    print(x)
                else:
                    y=header[column]
                    for x in x:
                        ofile.write(x[y]+"\n")
                column+=1
        rownum+=1
    ofile.close()
```

Running the above code produce the data line by line:

```
1 person found this helpful

1 person found this helpful
Adam
John
Smith
1 person found this helpful

1 person found this helpful
John
Mary
Smith
```

So how to save data in table (csv) format as described above?

Comment: Don't call `ofile.write()` each time through the `for col in row` loop. Append each column to a string, and write it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input data layout is certainly somewhat convoluted, but I think what the following does is at least fairly close to what you want done.

You didn't really specify the output csv file's formatting, so I just guessed and used `|` characters as delimiters. The columns don't line up nice as shown in your question, but that shouldn't matter in a csv file.

```
import csv
import json

with open('helpful.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as infile, \
     open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as outfile:

    fieldnames = 'helpful_reply', 'reply_by', 'thread_id'  # output file
    csvreader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')

    next(csvreader)  # skip header of input file
    csvwriter.writeheader()  # write header of output file

    # read and write rows of both files
    for row in csvreader:
        data = [json.loads(col) for col in row]
        thread_id = data[2]
        for helpful_reply, reply_by in zip(data[0], data[1]):
            row = dict(**helpful_reply, **reply_by, thread_id=thread_id)
            if not row['helpful_reply']: row['helpful_reply'] = "NULL"
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Contents of the `output.csv` file produced from your sample input data:

```
helpful_reply|reply_by|thread_id
1 person found this helpful|Adam|149617
NULL|John|149617
1 person found this helpful|Smith|149617
1 person found this helpful|John|147223
NULL|Mary|147223
1 person found this helpful|Smith|147223
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is a little bit twisted: a list of replies then a list of users, so you need to make sure the order is conserved, but anyway without going into CSV details, once you have one `row`:

```
helpful_reply_list = json.loads(row[0])
reply_by_list = json.loads(row[1])
thread_id = row[2]

# Printing it to make it simpler in my code, you put it in a file
for helpful_reply, reply_by in zip(helpful_reply_list, reply_by_list):
    print '%s\t%s\t%s\n' % (
        helpful_reply["helpful_reply"] or None,
        reply_by["reply_by"],
        thread_id["thread_id"])
```

Do this for every `row` and you are done